# How to open 5672 port on rabbitMQ server

Tags: rabbitmq

My locally installed rabbitMQ server must provide 5672 port for outer users. But it failed! I can only connect to localhost:5672! My rabbitmq.config file is empty!
So how can i let outer users to connect to 5672 port?
PS. I created new user User1 with full rights

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Mac, then probably you need to check /usr/local/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf to see if the file has NODE_IP_ADDRESS with "localhost". Remove it will allow others to connect to your RMQ instance.

Comment: Check https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html. It looks like for Windows, RABBITMQ_NODE_IP_ADDRESS is defined as environment variable, not in the file. Check if your current env if RABBITMQ_NODE_IP_ADDRESS has "localhost" or something, and then if it is, remove it and reinstall the RMQ service. That's what the page I linked above says. Reloading the environment variable isn't enough to take an effect.

Comment: system env variable RABBITMQ_NODE_IP_ADDRESS is not defined(